# JavaScript: Shuffling a deck, but it does NOT create a new shuffled deck each time using the original list

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a deck. I take a number of cards as input. For example, numCards = 5, so the deck (list) becomes [0,1,2,3,4]. The problem is that the while loop in the test_order(i,j,l) function is not shuffling properly. Function console.log(m) should print a new shuffled deck/list using the original list (l) but it keeps printing [0,1,2,3,4] after the first correct shuffle. It should create a newly shuffled deck each time using the original list, instead, it keeps repeating the original list or 1st shuffled list.

The purpose of the program is to find the probability of the number of times a card labeled i is above card labeled j after shuffles.

```
function list(numCards){
    var newList = []
    var i = 0;
    while (i < numCards){
        newList.push(i);
        i++;
    }
    return newList
}

function top_to_random(l){
    while(numPerformed != 0){
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * l.length);
        l.splice(x, 0, l.shift())
        numPerformed--;
    }
    return l
}

function test_order(i,j,l){ //PROBLEM IS IN HERE!!!!
    var n = 0
    var trials = 10
    var count = 0
    while (count < trials){ // PROBLEM IN WHILE LOOP
        let arrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(l));
        //console.log(arrayCopy)
        var m = top_to_random(arrayCopy)
        m.indexOf(i) < m.indexOf(j) ? n++ : n = n + 0
        
        //console.log(arrayCopy)
        console.log(m)
        count++
    }
    var prob = n/trials
    return  prob
}

//Argument Inputs
var numCards = parseInt(prompt("Enter number of cards in deck: "))
var l = list(numCards)
var numPerformed = parseInt(prompt("Enter number of shuffles to perform on deck: "));
var i = parseInt(prompt("i: "))
var j = parseInt(prompt("j: "))

//Execution
console.log(test_order(i,j,l))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not where you think it is, it's in your `top_to_random` function. You count the number of mixes done in your shuffle down from `numPerformed`, but this is a global-scope variable, so its not reset at each call. You should pass the mix count as a parameter like this:

```js
function top_to_random(l, mixNum){
    for (;mixNum > 0; mixNum--) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * l.length);
        l.splice(x, 0, l.shift());
    }
    return l;
}
```

Fixing a number of your syntax miconstructs, I get this code:

```js
function list(numCards){
    var newList = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < numCards){
        newList.push(i);
        i++;
    }
    return newList;
}

function top_to_random(l, mixNum){
    for (;mixNum > 0; mixNum--) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * l.length);
        l.splice(x, 0, l.shift());
    }
    return l;
}

function test_order(i,j,l){ //Problem is NOT in here
    let n = 0;
    let trials = 10;
    for (let count = 0; count < trials; count++) { // No not here
        let arrayCopy = [...l];
        top_to_random(arrayCopy, numPerformed);
        console.log(arrayCopy)
        if (arrayCopy.indexOf(i) < arrayCopy.indexOf(j)) n++;
        
        console.log(arrayCopy);
    }
    var prob = n/trials;
    return  prob;
}

// Argument Inputs
var numCards = parseInt(prompt("Enter number of cards in deck: "));
var l = list(numCards);
var numPerformed = parseInt(prompt("Enter number of shuffles to perform on deck: "));
var i = parseInt(prompt("i: "));
var j = parseInt(prompt("j: "));

//Execution
console.log(test_order(i,j,l));
```

Also You should be more careful about details when you code:

- You have a lot of missing semicolons
- You're mixing function arguments and global variables with no logic to the decision
- Don't use `while` when you should be using `for`
- Ternary operator to perform a simple if ?
- You'd better use `const` and `let` instead of `var`. For one thing it would have saved you this error

Better written code:

```js
const SHUFFLE_REPEATS = 10;

function list(numCards) {
    const newList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
        newList.push(i);
    return newList;
}

function top_to_random(l, mixNum) {
    for (; mixNum > 0; mixNum--) {
        const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * l.length);
        l.splice(x, 0, l.shift());
    }
    return l;
}

function test_order(i, j, l) {
    let n = 0;
    for (let count = 0; count < SHUFFLE_REPEATS; count++) {
        const arrayCopy = [...l];
        top_to_random(arrayCopy, numPerformed);
        console.log(arrayCopy)
        if (arrayCopy.indexOf(i) < arrayCopy.indexOf(j)) n++;
    }
    return n / SHUFFLE_REPEATS;
}

// Argument Inputs
const numCards = parseInt(prompt("Enter number of cards in deck: "));
const l = list(numCards);
const numPerformed = parseInt(prompt("Enter number of shuffles to perform on deck: "));
const i = parseInt(prompt("i: "));
const j = parseInt(prompt("j: "));

//Execution
console.log(test_order(i,j,l));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Could you please explain what does -> let arrayCopy = [...l]; do?

Comment: @NewbieCoder it's the spread operator applied to array and it returns a CLONED array, e.g. a different reference to an array containing the same elements.